# How to require an CJS module into a ES6 module in native Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, es6-modules

I use ES6 modules in Nodejs this way: `node --experimental-modules index.mjs`.

#### index.mjs

```
import express from 'express'
```

But I also need to import some third party modules that formatted in CommonJS:

```js
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom')
```

(took JSDom here but it also applies to other third party like [Airtable](https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js) for example)

#### question

It seems like I cannot mix both.
Is there a wrapper to force importing a CJS module into an ES6 module?

I don't use (and want to keep away from) Babel and Webpack for my project.
However I would be ok to transpile the third-party libs if absolutely necessary.